# Sharepoint 2013 publishing page creation using Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model

I am using SharePoint 2013. Is there any way I can programmatically create a page using ONLY th Client Object Model? Also notice that the page should be editable for further use.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PublishingWeb.AddPublishingPage method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.publishingweb.addpublishingpage) to create a new [PublishingPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.publishingpage) object in the PublishingWeb from [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.aspx) in SharePoint 2013 CSOM.

**Example**

```
public static PublishingPage CreatePublishingPage(ClientContext ctx, string pageName, string pageLayoutName)
{
    var pubWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(ctx, ctx.Web);
    var pageInfo = new PublishingPageInformation
    {
        Name = pageName,
        PageLayoutListItem = GetPageLayoutByName(ctx, pageLayoutName)
    };
    var publishingPage = pubWeb.AddPublishingPage(pageInfo);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    return publishingPage;
}



public static ListItem GetPageLayoutByName(ClientContext ctx, string name)
{
    var list = ctx.Site.GetCatalog((int)ListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog);
    var qry = new CamlQuery
    {
        ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>",name)
    };
    var result = list.GetItems(qry);
    ctx.Load(result);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    var item = result.FirstOrDefault();
    return item;
}
```

Usage

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    var page = CreatePublishingPage(ctx, "Welcome.aspx", "BlankWebPartPage.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prasannabalajim/archive/2013/05/20/how-to-add-a-publishing-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-client-object-model.aspx

This seems to be the answer, but I haven't tested it!

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.